# Variable selection using mixed-models (lme4)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, feature-selection

I want to model the infection rates in bees based on weather conditions. The weather variables are rolling means for different time periods and durations. Dependent data is infection levels gathered in March and the independent variables are the weather aggregates (e.g. from 30 day period from Jan1-Jan30, 90 day period from Dec1-Feb28), a few thousands of them and highly correlated.

PCA techniques did not work since the infections are not so strongly related to weather. I have also tried Bayesian Model Averaging and Boosted Regression Trees, since variables could be selected based on variable importance they calculate.

But since, my data is longitudinal and my apiaries have a fixed location, I think mixed-models are a good choice. Is there a way to do variable selection based on mixed-models?

What I have done now is to
1. run `glmer` for each of the independent variables separately,
2. remove those variable whose p-values for fixed-effect estimates are below 0.05 (not sure if this is a right thing - if the estimate for a variable is not significant, that variable being the only one in the model, it is right to drop that variable, is it?)
3. from the variables that are left over, test for correlation between the variables
4. remove the variables that are highly correlated, giving preference to the variable that has the lowest AIC.

Or should I at this stage, not worry about p-values of Intercepts and only focus on AIC (or BIC)? since some of the variables have high p-values but AICs lower than than those with low p-values.

I have tried reading up a lot, and there is no one fool-proof solution for variable selection, but would like to know if there is anything inherently wrong with my method. As I am not a statistician, equations often look like beautiful Arabic calligraphy and there lies my dead-end.

Comment: Check out the `glmmLasso` package.